# How can i convert an user ID to a member object using Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to convert a user ID that I store in a sqlite3 database into a member object, so I can get the `.display_name` attribute of that user.

```python
    channel_id = ctx.channel.id
    c.execute(f"SELECT * FROM deleted_messages WHERE channel_id={channel_id}")
    array = c.fetchone()
    message_text = array[1]
    author_id = array[2]
    guild = bot.get_guild(GUILD_ID) #Here I usually have the ID of the guild that the bot is in.
    author = guild.get_member(author_id)
    
    author.display_name #When I try to get the diplay_name of that member, I get the error.
```

This is the error that I get:

`discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'display_name'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`guild.get_member(author_id)` this is returning `None`.

You have to check first if the author your received is a member object.

Furthermroe you probably don't have Member Intents enabled. [Enable that](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html?highlight=member%20intents) or use the [coroutine `fetch_member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=get_member#discord.Guild.fetch_member)

Comment: Thanks, the problem was that I didn't have [this setting](http://prntscr.com/vem82p) enabled. Once I enabled that and used the coroutine fetch_member it worked.